# Suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains

Tags: java

I am getting the following warning from my NetBeans IDE.

```
Suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains
Expected type T, actual type Object
```

May I know what does that means?

This doesn't make sense to me. Both `List` and `Collection` class's `contains` method, are using Object as their method parameter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author yan-cheng.cheok
 */
public abstract class AbstractCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {

    protected List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // Suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains
        // Expected type T, actual type Object
        return list.contains(o);
    }
```

---

**Code snippet from Collection class**

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this collection contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this collection
 * contains at least one element <tt>e</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
 *
 * @param o element whose presence in this collection is to be tested
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this collection contains the specified
 *         element
 * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
 *         is incompatible with this collection (optional)
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
 *         collection does not permit null elements (optional)
 */
boolean contains(Object o);
```

---

**Code snippet from List class**

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this list contains
 * at least one element <tt>e</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
 *
 * @param o element whose presence in this list is to be tested
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element
 * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
 *         is incompatible with this list (optional)
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
 *         list does not permit null elements (optional)
 */
boolean contains(Object o);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the call to list.contains you are comparing an object to a type T.  Casting o to type T should resolve your warning.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the `Object` declaration to `T` a better option?

Comment: @Bobby: Actually, it's an implementation of abstract method defined in `Collection` interface. Hence, we have to stick with the declaration.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari: I'm not that experienced in Java, but shouldn't the `Collection<T>` have a `contains(T item)` instead of a `contains(Object item)` method? Or did you mean that `Collection<T>` is inheriting from `Collection` and therefor the `Object` declaration is necessary?

Comment: refixed.  I should go to bed.  I'm getting sloppy

Comment: @Bobby: `Collection<E>` interface declared the method `boolean contains(Object o)`. So, if you are implementing that interface you have to provide the implementation for that method. For example you can look into the source, or may be just docs, of `ArrayList`. That is also implementing `Collection<E>` interface.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense to me. Both List and Collection class's contains method, are using Object as their method parameter. See my edited post.

Comment: Yes, by stating that you are making a list of Type T you are forcing .contains to check against a generic object class.  Since T is also an object this is allowed.  However, various implementations of T may cause problems when doing a comparison.  Thus by forcing the incoming object to adhere to a generic form of T removes this potential conflict.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: Why not just check the source of `ArrayList`. Then you will understand it better, IMO.

Comment: The only reason the signature looks like this: `boolean contains(Object o)` and does not use `T` is backwards compatibility. Before Java 5 there were no generics and one could call `contains` with an object of the wrong type and always gets `false`. Since these programs should still compile and work as before, the signature expects an Object. However, most IDEs will warn you about wrong data types in generic Collections though.

Answer (score 3):

Calling the contains method with an Object instead of the generic type may be a programming error. Since the code is still valid the compiler will only show a warning.

An example why this warning is necessary:

```
List<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();
l.add(1l);
l.contains(1);
```

The code is valid but would always return false. An error that is normally hidden by contains accepting object instead of a generic type, so the compiler is limited to warnings.

Since there are valid use cases for passing an object, you should be able to use a @SuppressWarnings() annotation to hide this warning (only do this if you know what you are doing).